# Forge design automation for Revit fail after our code finish

Tags: revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

We are experimenting with Design automation for Revit and have gotten stuck on a failure that is hard to debug:
basically our code finish and then forge takes over and fails.
Here is part of the log: I have marked in green what part are "our" logs:
[image]

Basically the app takes an rfa and should output a json.
I have defined the activity like this:
[image]

What can I do to investigate what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue:
you need to explicitly set the Succeeded property to true on the DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs. Otherwise it will report as failed.

Comment: Yes, correct! The `DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs.Succeeded` must be true like here
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step1-convert-addin/#step-6-add-an-event-handler-for-designautomationready